# How I can to create table with vertical scroolbar and Horizontal and vertical Border between fields in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build table with vertical scroolbar and Horizontal and vertical Border between fields but I failed , 
my try :

```
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

and this div :

```
   <div style="overflow:scroll;height:80px;width:100%;overflow:scroll">

    <table width="800" border="0"  class="my-table">
      <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr> 
        <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr>
    </table>  

 </div>
```

the result is :
[here only the Horizontal scrool appare but I want to vertical scrool appare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSgW2.png)

the fist problem :
vertical scroolbar not appare 
the second problem :
I want to add title to table and  format this title in style different of style table like this picture :
[see to cells of title have style different of the reset of cells in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VneB5.png)

so any help to solve my tow problem ?